# bxSlider onSlideBefore newbieQ

Tags: bxslider

I am trying to adjust the opacity of the centre slide in a carousel of three (to emulate this site http://www.tyinarchitects.com/) in a responsive slider using bxSlider, but cannot get the syntax right.

When I use $slideElement.addClass('active-slide'); the effect happens, just on the wrong slides, so while my basic idea works I need to reference the slide using oldIndex and NewIndex rather than $slideElement.

I tried various permutations of:-

```
$slider.children.eq(oldIndex).removeClass('active-slide');
$slider.$children.eq(oldIndex).removeClass('active-slide');
$('.slider2').children.eq(newIndex).addClass('active-slide');
```

And they all just clog up the works so my JS syntax is obviously not right. Can anyone take pity on me?

The complete working code is

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider2').bxSlider({
    slideWidth: 300,
    minSlides: 3,
    maxSlides: 3,
    moveSlides: 1,
    slideMargin: 0,
    pager: false,
    auto: true,
    onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
    $slideElement.addClass('active-slide');
            },
    onSlideAfter: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
    $slideElement.removeClass('active-slide');
            }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume your HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="slide">Slide 1</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 2</div>
    <div class="slide">Slide 3</div>
</div>
```

Then you could try the following:

```
onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex) {
    $('#container>div').eq(newIndex).addClass('active-slide'));
}
```